# Two classes -How to access the object of one class from another?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, class

I have two classes, `TProvider` and `TEncrypt`. The calling application will talk to the `TProvider` class. The calling application will call `Initialise` first to obtain the handle `mhProvider`. I require access to this handle later when i try to perform encryption, as the `TEncrypt` class donot have access to this handle `mhProvider`. How can i get access to this handle?

```
class TProvider
{
public:
    int Initialise();
    int Encrypt();
private:
    HCRYPTPROV mhProvider;
    TEncrypt* mpEncrypt;
};
    //------------------------------------
class TEncrypt
{
public:
    int Encryption();
private:
    int GenerateEncryptionKey();
    HCRYPTKEY mhKey;
};
    //------------------------------------
int TEncrypt::Encryption()
{
    vStatus = GenerateEncryptionKey();
    // will go on to perform encryption after obtaining the key
return(vStatus);
}
    //------------------------------------
int TEncrypt::GenerateEncryptionKey()
{
    BOOL bRet = CryptGenKey(mhProvider,
                            CALG_AES_256,
                            CRYPT_EXPORTABLE,
                            &mhKey);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either you pass the handle to TEncrypt via a *(constructor/method) parameter*, or you make it available via a *global variable*. I would prefer the former, as global variables make the code harder to understand, maintain and test.

Availability may also be indirect, e.g. you pass an object to `TEncrypt::Encryption()` which provides access to the handle via one of its public methods.

(of course you can also pass it through a file, DB, ... but let's keep the focus within the program.)

#### Update: an example

```
class TEncrypt
{
public:
    int Encrypt(HCRYPTPROV& mhProvider);
private:
    int GenerateEncryptionKey(HCRYPTPROV& mhProvider);
    HCRYPTKEY mhKey;
};
    //------------------------------------
int TEncrypt::Encrypt(HCRYPTPROV& mhProvider)
{
    vStatus = GenerateEncryptionKey(mhProvider);
    // will go on to perform encryption after obtaining the key
    return(vStatus);
}
    //------------------------------------
int TEncrypt::GenerateEncryptionKey(HCRYPTPROV& mhProvider)
{
    BOOL bRet = CryptGenKey(mhProvider,
                            CALG_AES_256,
                            CRYPT_EXPORTABLE,
                            &mhKey);
}
```

Note: I renamed `TEncrypt::Encrypt` because it is better to use verbs as method names rather than nouns.

Comment: class TEncrypt { public: int Encryption(HCRYPTPROV& mhProvider); private: int GenerateEncryptionKey(); HCRYPTKEY mhKey; }; Is this is what you are referring? Can you please show me your explnation as a snippet? Thanks

Comment: @Raj, yes, that would be the simplest solution. I did not provide an example because there can be so many variations, and without knowing more of the context it is impossible to choose. But I added one now.

Answer (score 1):

Use a getter in the `TProvider` class, instead of `Initialise` to handle talk between classes:

```
HCRYPTPROV TProvider::get_hProvider() const
{
    return mhProvider;
}
```

You could have a look at the [Mediator Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mediator_pattern) too.

Comment: When you refer as getter, can you please explain me with a snippet? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If `mhProvider` is needed by `TEncrypt`, then why is it in the class `TProvider`? Somehow your classes don't look to be properly designed.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pass it to `TEncrypt`'s constructor or `Encryption` member function?